# Convert float to time

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I have the following Dataframe df:

[image: Dataframe]

Now i want to convert the column "ABZEIT" to time format. So the first rows would be:
13:05; 15:40; 14:20; 16:30; 7:40;...

After converting the column to string i tried:

```
df["ABZEIT"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ABZEIT"], format="%H.%M")
```

Problem is, that for example 15.4 is converted to 15:04 instead of 15:40.

Answer (score 0):

The `%M` expects minutes to be formatted as two digit, zero padded value ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)):

`| %M | Minute as a zero-padded decimal number. | 00, 01, …, 59 |`

so you should ensure your input string is in expected format (also note you hand it a string, not a float):

```py
import pandas as pd

tmp = "15.4".split('.')
time_string = f'{tmp[0]}.{tmp[1]:02}'
time_datetime = pd.to_datetime(time_string, format="%H.%M")
print(time_datetime)
```

which would produce expected

```
1900-01-01 15:40:00
```

Remember not to pad hours the same way as actually you want `1` to be `1` and not `10`.